# If L1 is undecidable and L1 is included in L2, is L2 also undecidable and why?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

If you could reduce L1 to L2 then L2 would be undeciable of course. But I am wondering if you could really recude in all cases. Thanks for all kind of help

Comment: What do you mean by "included"? If it's a subset, the certainly not: every language is a subset of the very decidable language consisting of all strings.

Comment: Yes, i mean subset

Answer (score 1):

No. Every language is a subset of the language containing all strings, which is trivially decidable.